# How to de-scuff patent leather shoes

Tags: shoes

I was recently performing Colorguard Honors at a Veterans' motorcade.  For pictures (in case you're wondering) see [my Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/20lbfp8vp1rbsa3/AAAKxqjxs-18fmBhUpBCY_Opa?dl=0)

Unfortunately, some genius decided to use a piece of cinder block to prop the door open, and I got my shoe scuffed up pretty bad when it decided to let go.

[image: image of scuffed shoe]

It looks worse than that in person.

How should I get rid of that scuff?  These are my regular parade shoes so I want them as beautiful as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nail polish remover or Rubbing Alcohol works!.

Apply a little nail polish remover or Rubbing Alcohol to a cotton ball to polish out the scuff marks. Then, apply baby powder or petroleum jelly, like Vaseline, to protect the shoe's material. This method works well for Patent Leather.

Comment: even patent leather?

Comment: absolutely! this method will remove your scuff marks, feel free to test it on a sample area if that helps give you peace of mind. Again, this method works!

Comment: I'll definitely try it

Comment: Cool please comment on here to let everyone know that it worked after you try it incase someone crosses this page later on down the road with the same question :) Thanks!

Comment: I'm about to try it... Will let you know as soon as I do...

Comment: Just tried it, and it didn't fix it completely, but it definitely made it look less horrible!  Now I'm all ready for tonight, thanks!

Comment: Awesome glad to hear! GL tonight!